# String substitution with sed

Tags: awk, sed, ksh

I'd like to do the following transformation within a file (named inputfile) with sed

Searched line :

`$CmdVar $ENV\util.exe firstparm secondparm`

Searched pattern is util.exe ; firstparm and secondparm are always the last two words.
The job consists in commenting the matching whole line with ###, a tag (mytag), ###, the searched pattern, ###, and the two parameters followed by ### again.

So expected output would be :

`###mytag###util.exe###firstparm secondparm### $CmdVar $ENV\util.exe firstparm secondparm`

i'm thinking of combining some grep/awk and a loop in order to collect relevant information to use sed by specifying line number.

> ```
> info=`grep -n "util.exe" inputfile | awk '{print $1,$(NF-1),$NF","}'`
> if [ ! -z $info ]; then
>   tr , '\n' <<<"$info" | while read;
>   do
>     words=${REPLY}
>   # use sed here by splitting $words  
>   done
> fi
> ```

Because of the high number of files i have to handle, this might take a lot of time.

Is there any a more straightforward way to use sed or awk to achieve this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your input looks like you are using windows, but you added bash and ksh. This is not the same, choose relevant tags! Are you in WSL, cygwin, git bash? Always give the context accurately.

Comment: Done, sorry for the confusion!

Comment: `ksh` on Windows? Are you sure?

Comment: You say "Because of the high number of files i have to handle" - if you have multiple files to handle then provide multiple sample input files and the associated expected output. For sample input, don't just provide 1 line that matches, provide multiple lines per file, including lines that don't match, especially rainy day cases - for example if `fooutil.exe` or `util.executed` or `utilrexe` existed in the input should it appear in the output?

Comment: Should lines that do not contain `util.exe` be printed? Etc... It's important that you provide a [mcve] we can copy/paste to test with and get a simple pass/fail result. A script that doesn't work for your real data could produce your current expected output from your current sample input therefore your example isn't adequate to demonstrate and test your requirements. You don't need grep, sed, tr, and/or a shell while-read loop to manipulate text when you're using awk btw.

Comment: Your grep+awk are outputting the line number from the input file but that's not present in your expected output, and your script is doing `tr , '\n' <<<"$info"` but there are no `,`s in your sample input and only 1 being added by awk at the end of the output (why print `,` then change it to `\n`?), so your code doesn't appear to match your example. Please make sure the sample input/output you provide is truly representative of your real data.

Comment: fwiw, once you pull `awk` into the equation there's a good chance you can eliminate the need for `grep`, `tr` and `sed`, ie, you can probably do the whole thing with a single `awk` script; having said that ... as Ed's already mentioned, we need to see a more complete set of sample inputs (2-3 files, 2-4 lines per file, matching and non-matching lines should suffice; then the matching expected output for those files)

Comment: @GillesQuénot, yes i'm dealing with some windows scripts that've been uploaded on a linux sever

Comment: @EdMorton, will give you additionnal infos asap

Comment: You already accepted an answer so you should post a new question with the missing information, don't update this one now.

Comment: Okay @EdMorton, sorry for misbehaving, i'm pretty new to all this.

Comment: No problem, I'm just trying to help you get answers same as everyone else here, and we all know there's a learning curve to using the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If query is a regex:

```
awk '
    $0 ~ q {
        printf "###%s###%s###%s %s### ",
            tag, q, $(NF-1), $(NF)
    }
    { print }
' tag='mytag' q='util.exe' inputfile >outputfile
```

If query is a plain string:

```
awk '
    index(q) {
        printf "###%s###%s###%s %s### ",
            tag, q, $(NF-1), $(NF)
    }
    { print }
' tag='mytag' q='util.exe' inputfile >outputfile
```

Comment: Wow. So fast. And easily readable. Thanks a million @jhnc.
Is there any way to add exclusion patterns and keeping that syntax?
Lets say, not starting with # or not containing echo?

Comment: You'll have to be explicit about your requirements, but it sounds do-able with PCRE lookahead. That rules out awk, but perl and other general purpose languages can handle it.

Comment: @MisterClaret [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) are strongly discouraged, ask a new question if you can't figure out how to do whatever you want to do now.

Comment: Regarding "Is there any way to add exclusion patterns and keeping that syntax?" - the answer depends on what you mean by "that syntax". I'd say the answer is yes because I don't consider it necessary to use a single regexp to capture all of your requirements and I'd consider such a solution as still being "that syntax". But until we see your question with a [mcve], we're just guessing.